# recreate this web request in vb net

Tags: vb.net, webclient

i?m trying to make automatic image set in  pinterest account with WebClient.

I'd like to recreate this http request: 
(Request-Line)  POST /upload-image/?img=Desert.jpg HTTP/1.1
**Host**    www.pinterest.com

**User-Agent**  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0

**Accept**  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

**Accept-Language** it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

**Accept-Encoding** gzip, deflate

**X-Requested-With**    XMLHttpRequest

**X-File-Name** Desert.jpg

**Cache-Control**   no-cache

**X-CSRFToken** RqwJCawJyAGYIZfzob51qxrEGj4GJcSA

**Referer** https://www.pinterest.com

**Content-Length**  846128

**Content-Type**    multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------5431268530037

**Cookie**  _pinterest_cm=TWc9PSY1YlkwcmtVRGlNRzRQZXpiZXJseVl6TnFHYnEvZlhpNDZPcExCQnhKN3UvdUUveWI0c3p4bWJKUmhoZy9YRG9sS3dNZTZFSFNhN2V3VWhJM1JkbUlxbC92VjhHUGFldlRTVVJTNlA1L1M0SDE5QXhLcHVWS2ZrSUh3NTN2ODA0WSZ5dnpJQkVRUmx5TVJGTEdmQm5EVmRGQXNqbDQ9; csrftoken=RqwJCawJyAGYIZfzob51qxrEGj4GJcSA; _pinterest_sess="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"; sessionFunnelEventLogged=1; __utma=229774877.448600758.1436737610.1436739423.1436745191.3; __utmz=229774877.1436737610.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); c_dpr=1; __utmc=229774877; _b="ARLbRMvYKUdKiaBWDA2Oxko87z7iIN4MuGnJALvZK8vehgzT11AKeoa13PH4l9VjVMU="; _pinterest_pfob=disabled; __utmb=229774877.3.9.1436745219732; __utmt=1

**Connection**  keep-alive

**Pragma**  no-cache

I have try this code, but i can't obtain Content-Length and Content-Type.

```
        Dim wc As New WebClient

        wc.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        wc.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("pippomio@yahoo.com", "88Y71nR3764")
        wc.Headers.Add("Host", "www.pinterest.com")
        wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5")
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
        wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
        wc.Headers.Add("X-File-Name", "Hydrangeas.jpg")
        wc.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        wc.Headers.Add("X-CSRFToken", token)
        wc.Headers.Add("Referer", "https://www.pinterest.com")
        wc.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
        wc.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no - cache")

        Dim Response As Byte() = wc.UploadFile("https://www.pinterest.com/upload-image/?img=Hydrangeas.jpg", "POST", "Hydrangeas.jpg")
```

In wich way can I do this request in vb net?
Thanks

Comment: https://developers.pinterest.com/

Comment: sorry, but ican't mode to upload and set image profile. the only way semm httprequest. I'm tryng with geckofx control, but i can't manage file uoload

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you to check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tutorial to learn how to send/receive HTTP requests on correct way.

Second, you should not re-do any web browser actions in your program since it is usually not a good practice as the frontend architecture should be subject an unexpected change any time. Instead of this, you should check [Pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/), especially the [Users API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/users/) which can help you to achieve your plans. Usually API interfaces are not a subject of random changes, they are more reliable than replaying front-end operations and more stable, has more capabilities to the load.

(Pinterest API seems working only from Firefox, if you get an empty area at right side with a big "None" text, then browse the link from Firefox - it seems can handle the page)